# Why is the る left off すぎる in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Here is my sentence.

> おしろ　あんたが頼みすぎなんだよ。

First, I'm not sure what おしろ means, perhaps somewhat could inform me since Jisho and google translate are both giving results that I don't think are correct. I'm thinking it's some sort of slang.

Now for the main question. I believe the なんだ to be the explanatory の and this sentence means, "(The thing is) You ask for too much." What's the reasoning for taking the る off here? すぎ would be the stem of すぎる. Every example I've ever come across of explanatory の with a verb has not used the stem. What's the difference here?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5355/16104 related.

Comment: 「おしろ」じゃなくて「 **む**しろ」じゃないですかね。。。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Masu-stem of a verb often [works as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). Here 頼みすぎ is a *noun* meaning something like "over-asking".

Also note that 頼みすぎ is followed by な, which comes only after a noun or a na-adjective. 頼みすぎるなんだ is plain ungrammatical. Please check [this list](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5399/5010) for the usage patterns of explanatory-な.

Compare:

> - 彼は食べ過ぎだ。 He is eating too much. (Literally "As for him, it's over-eating")
> - 彼は食べ過ぎる。 He (always) eats too much.
> - 彼は食べ過ぎるんだ。 It is that he (always) eats too much.
> - 彼は食べ過ぎている。 He is eating too much.

As for おしろ, I also guess you've misread [むしろ](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%80%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D). Or it may be someone's name.

Comment: It is  むしろ. I was reading on my kindle and I guess my eye's didn't pick it up properly. Thanks a lot.